# Google Chrome browser - show and hide elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome

This is my sample code (jQuery):

```
$('#anyElement').click(function() {
    $('#progress').show() ;
    /**
    loading result with ajax
    time it about 2 sec.
    */
   $('#progress').hide() ;
   $('#resultDisplay').show() ; // display result of ajax
}) ;
```

All browsers (not Chrome) works:

1. anyElement -> click
2. progress -> show
3. function returns the result of ajax: reqest -> server response after 2 seconds
4. progress -> hide
5. resultDisplay -> show result of ajax

but chrome:

1. anyElement -> click
2. function returns the result of ajax: reqest -> server response after 2 seconds
3. resultDisplay -> show result of ajax

When I use the tools for developers and the code is executed step by step, everything works fine. Could someone explain this to me?
Thanks.

Comment: Your problem isn't clear, but it sounds like you need to put the second part of your code in the callback of the AJAX request.

Comment: Can you add the ajax snippet so we can see the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Here's something you could try.

Wrap your ajax call in a settimeout, that way Chrome has time to actually show the progress element.

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //Code to run your ajax call and hide the progress image.
},250)
```

This is only adding a 1/4 second delay, in fact you could probably experiment and bring that down to a much smaller delay, but it returns control of the browser to actually update the elements shown to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your ajax call and how its wrapped it sounds like chrome isnt waiting for it to complete before moving on to the next line of code. ajax calls by definition are asynchronous so javascript doesnt wait for the call to finish before moving on.
This means that your code is calling `progress.show()` and then `ajax` and then `progress.hide()` but because the ajax call is asynchronous its like `progress.show()` and `progress.hide()` are being called next to each other - ie, so quickly that its hard to register their effects.
jQuery has a `$.when()` function that will wait for your ajax call to complete before moving on to the next bit of your code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a possible where your AJAX call async is set to false and the progress is a gif loader, then the gif stops moving on Chrome due to synchronous call. If this is the case, then solution is not to use synchronous call. You can hide the progress when the ajax completes.

```
$.ajax({
     ...
     success: function() {
          $('#progress').hide() ;
          $('#resultDisplay').show() ;
     }
});
```